# Oracle PLSQL fetch multiple row/column value of number data type into a collection of number type?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, collections

We have a table that was designed to have multiple columns with number data types that stores a primary key from another table. Each row has a unique organization id. So the structure looks like this.

```
create table matrix_table (
    id number primary key
  , emp_id1 number
  , emp_id2 number
  , emp_id3 number
  , emp_id4 number
)
/
insert into matrix_table values ( 1, 100, 101, 102, 103 )
/
insert into matrix_table values ( 2, 200, 201, 202, 203 )
/
insert into matrix_table values ( 3, 300, 301, 302, 303 )
/
insert into matrix_table values ( 4, 400, 401, 402, 403 )
/

create type emp_ids is table of number
/
```

Then I try to do it like this but it doesn't work since it is expecting a collection of emp_ids

```
declare
  l_emp_ids emp_ids := emp_ids();
begin
select emp_ids(emp_id1, emp_id2, emp_id3, emp_id4)
  bulk collect
  into l_emp_ids
  from matrix_table;
end;

ORA-06550: line 4, column 12: PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got APPS.EMP_IDS
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I also tried without the bulk collect but again it won't work since it is expecting only 1 record whereas I have 4.

```
declare
  l_emp_ids emp_ids := emp_ids();
begin
select emp_ids(emp_id1, emp_id2, emp_id3, emp_id4)
  into l_emp_ids
  from matrix_table;
end;

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

I know this can via union or thru loop but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do it.

Reason I'm doing this is because later on I need to join this with another table. Kind of like this.

```
select e.*
  from employees e
     , table ( emp_ids_var ) v
 where e.emp_id = v.column_value
```

For reference, here's our database details:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                      
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                                  
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                              
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we need to create an object type first.

```
create type obj_ids is object (
 emp_id1 number
  , emp_id2 number
  , emp_id3 number
  , emp_id4 number
);
create type emp_ids is table of obj_ids;
```

And this should work:

```
declare
  l_emp_ids emp_ids := emp_ids();
begin
select obj_ids(emp_id1, emp_id2, emp_id3, emp_id4)
  bulk collect
  into l_emp_ids
  from matrix_table;
  
for i in 1..l_emp_ids.count
loop
dbms_output.put_line (l_emp_ids(i).emp_id1);
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: unfortunately that would still require me to specify the four columns which is what i'm trying to avoid since in the real table i'm using, it has more than 4.

Comment: I think that there's no simple way of doing it, because your (@ads) code is trying to put 4 values (columns) into a single-dimensional (1 column) collection, so you'll have to do it differently - either by using what @kuryuu suggested, or UNION of these values, or using dynamic SQL (which I don't like as it makes things complex), or some other approach.

Comment: @Littlefoot thanks. ended up using unpivot instead but still not my preferred approach since i had to specify the column names. but it did contain less code vs other approaches so far.